# normalization coefficient in the central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

why do we use normalization coefficient in the central limit theorem?

For CLT we use $\sqrt{n}$ as the normalization factor, but why do we need it?

Comment: I found the duplicates by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=central+limit+standardize).  One helpful key word was "standardize."  Please link to that search for further information.